# Pass custom data to Google Analytics with Goal Tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics with goal tracking to track when a user submits a form that is on every page of my website. Currently this tells me when the form has been submitted, but is there a way of passing through the page name as well so I can track what page the form has been sent from?

My goal tracking is set up with the Event goal type and I have configured the goal to use a category, action and label with the following code on the submit button, which works fine:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Total Form Submits', 'Submit', 'Form Submit']);"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the second dimension in the events report to "page" it will show you the path were the event was triggered. For goals you can see the info in the conversions->goal urls report. So you can see where your goal was triggered without additional code.

Answer (score 0):

You could also replace your event action or label with a "form name" that would allow you to identify your form. No point in sending in "submit" and "form submit".

An example, for a contact us form:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Total Form Submits', 'Contact Us', 'Submit']);"
```